# добавление в таблицу по условию

Tags: php, html, mysql

Нужна помощь с запросом, суть в том, что нужно добавить данные с формы в существующую таблицу по определенному условию, в моем случае для переменной `$_COOKIE['id']`
ВОт сам запрос

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
if (isset($_COOKIE['id']) and isset($_COOKIE['hash']))
{   
    echo $_COOKIE['id'];
   if (isset($_POST["FName"])) {
    //Вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user` (`f_name`) 
                        VALUES ('".$_POST['FName']."'" );
    //Если вставка прошла успешно
    if ($sql) {
        echo "<p>Данные успешно добавлены в таблицу.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>";
    }
}


}
        ?>
```

Comment: Проблема-то в чём?